# How can i get the image of a website using Selenium and Python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-web-driver

I'm using Selenium chrome-webdriver, with python, and I'm trying to download or get the base64 string of the image that pop-ups when trying to login to this site: https://coinmarketcap.com/it/account/my-diamonds/

I've tried to inspect the elements and click on the link of the image but I get: "*403 ERROR The request could not be satisfied*.", probably I haven't the permission to this image.

I've also tried with the following code:

```
ele = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[1]')))

# get the img as a base64 string
img_base64 = driver.execute_async_script("""
    var ele = arguments[0], callback = arguments[1];
    ele.addEventListener('load', function fn(){
      ele.removeEventListener('load', fn, false);
      var cnv = document.createElement('canvas');
      cnv.width = this.width; cnv.height = this.height;
      cnv.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0, 0);
      callback(cnv.toDataURL('image/jpeg').substring(22));
    }, false);
    ele.dispatchEvent(new Event('load'));
    """, ele)

print(img_base64)

# save the img to a file
with open(r"img.jpg", 'wb') as f:
    f.write(base64.b64decode(img_base64))
```

but I get :

> selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: script timeout

So, how can I do it somehow?

Comment: So you can not get to [this](https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/cloud/img/loyalty-program/diamond-icon.svg) link? Also, it's an SVG image -- why are you saving it to base64?

Comment: @Sparrow1029 no sorry, I was referring to this link: https://bin.bnbstatic.com/image/antibot/image/SLIDE/20211228/11/94b80e8eb9c14f5387c91d3489f12306.png (I made an error in the question)

Comment: Built-in method - [docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=image#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.get_screenshot_as_base64)

Comment: @edd but how can I make a screenshot of the element only, and not to the full page?